# Java collections - How to add multiple values in the collection?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, guava

How to add multiple values into multihashmap, since its not genric.Please see the below code.

**Please look it expected output : Col1,col2,col3,col4 order of display values not matching with col5 order.** Could you please advise me to handle all the values within multihashmap.

```
Iterator<Search> iterator = pre.iterator();
    MultiHashMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    List list = null;
    while(iterator.hasNext())       {
        Search prer = (Search)iterator.next();
        String product = prer.getProduct();
        sb.append(prer.getreqsNbr());
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(prer.getOp()));
        sb.append(" ");
        dependencies.put(product, sb.toString());
        sb.setLength(0);

        ***//This is for col1,col2,col3,col4***

        prer.getProductNbr()));
        prer.getProdDescr()));
        prer.getreqsNbr()));
        prer.getreqdescr()));
        }

    ***//This loop for get values as col5***

    Set set = mhm.entrySet();  
    Iterator i = set.iterator(); 
    while(i.hasNext()) { 
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); 
        list=(List)mhm.get(me.getKey()); 
        int itemCount = list.size();
        for (int z = 0; z < itemCount; z++) {
            String values = "";
            for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++)  { 
                values += list.get(j);      }
            System.out.println(me.getKey() + ": value :" + values); 
         }
```

Above program output:

```
c1   c2    c3  c4 c5
120  xxxx  12 xxx 14
120  xxxx  13 xxx 14
120  xxxx  14 xxx 14
130  xxxx  14 xxx 12 13 14
```

Expected output :

```
Col1  col2   col3  col4    col5
120   xxxx    12   xxxx    12 13 14
120   xxxx    13   xxxx    12 13 14     
120   xxxx    14   xxxx    12 13 14
130   xxxx    14   xxxx    14
```

Below setof code is working as expected(this for col5).

```
Set set = mhm.entrySet();  
    Iterator i = set.iterator(); 
    while(i.hasNext()) { 
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); 
        list=(List)mhm.get(me.getKey()); 
        int itemCount = list.size();
        for (int z = 0; z < itemCount; z++) {
            String values = "";
            for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++)  { 
                values += list.get(j);      }
            System.out.println(me.getKey() + ": value :" + values); 
         }
```

This part need to push multihash map and while displaying those are asociated each other (this is for col1,col2,col3,col4.

```
prer.getProductNbr()));
prer.getProdDescr()));
prer.getreqsNbr()));
prer.getreqdescr()));
```

Comment: Maybe you could include the order that you got as well as the order you expected.

Comment: sure, please give few mintues.

Comment: Your correct, this is org.apache.commons.collections.MultiHashMap;

Comment: column1 , clumn2 ,column 3 ,column 4 values are not associated with column 5.Because column 5 getting from multihashmap.

Comment: Guava supports 1.6 and above, but i using 1.5.

Comment: @user2444474 [Guava JDK5 backport](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/guava-announce/pAkjbCq_5Ek) is available as well.

Comment: Cool, i will try on that.

Answer (score 1):

This code will print the values many times

```
    int itemCount = list.size();
    for (int z = 0; z < itemCount; z++) {
        String values = "";
        for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++)  { 
            values += list.get(j);
        }
        System.out.println(me.getKey() + ": value :" + values); 
     }
```

You probably want something like this:

```
String values = "";
for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++)  { 
  values += list.get(j) + " ";
}
System.out.println(me.getKey() + ": value :" + values);
```

Comment: Have updated the question , please look it again.Sorry for inconvience.